# Ansible: Run command as different user but not with sudo

Tags: bash, ansible, sudo, pulseaudio

My overall aim is to restart pulseaudio for a specific user via ansible (so if you have a better idea how to do this, I am open to hear it :) )

I want to run the following command as the user `myuser`, and according to pulseaudio this should not be done as sudo/root.

```
$([[ $(pulseaudio -k) -eq 0 ]] || exit 0; sleep 5; [[ $(pulseaudio -D --exit-idle-time=-1) -eq 0 ]] || exit 0)
```

that works nice if I test it one the machine it self. It kills pulseaudio if it's running and than starts it again and it does not fail, if pulseaudio was already stopped.

#### Attempt 1 [Waiting til timeout for password]:

My ansible task (as part of a role) looks like this:

```
- name: restart pulse audio
  shell: '$([[ $(pulseaudio -k) -eq 0 ]] || exit 0; sleep 5; [[ $(pulseaudio -D --exit-idle-time=-1) -eq 0 ]] || exit 0)'
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_flags: "su - {{ ansible_user }} -c"
```

But if I run that I get the error `FAILED! => {"msg": "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: "}`

If I login to that machine as root and enter `sudo su - myuser` I get a prompt as `myuser` how I would expect it.

So how can I specify a password for `myuser` so ansible can use it?

#### Attempt 2 [Incorrect su password]:

ansible task:

```
- name: restart pulse audio
  shell: '$([[ $(pulseaudio -k) -eq 0 ]] || exit 0; sleep 5; [[ $(pulseaudio -D --exit-idle-time=-1) -eq 0 ]] || exit 0)'
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  become: true
  become_method: su
  become_user: myuser
```

I also tried to use `become_user` instead of the `become_flags` but with no success. Then I got the error: `FAILED! => {"msg": "Incorrect su password"}`

#### Attempt 3 [Command get's executed as sudo]:

If I tried Calum Halpin first suggestion, pulseaudio gets startet but as sudo, what is not what I want, I need pulseaudio to be startet by `myuser`.

ansible task:

```
- name: restart pulse audio
  shell: '$([[ $(pulseaudio -k) -eq 0 ]] || exit 0; sleep 5; [[ $(pulseaudio -D --exit-idle-time=-1) -eq 0 ]] || exit 0)'
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: myuser
```

I get the following output:

```
{"changed": true, 
"cmd": "$([[ $(pulseaudio -k) -eq 0 ]] || exit 0; sleep 5; [[ $(pulseaudio -D --exit-idle-time=-1) -eq 0 ]] || exit 0)", 
"delta": "0:00:05.110839", "end": "2019-06-23 11:11:43.686776", "rc": 0, "start": "2019-06-23 11:11:38.575937", 
"stderr": "E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such file or directory\nW: [pulseaudio] main.c: This program is not intended to be run as root (unless --system is specified).", 
"stderr_lines": ["E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such file or directory", "W: [pulseaudio] main.c: This program is not intended to be run as root (unless --system is specified)."], 
"stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

#### Attempt 2.1 & 3.1 [using `remote_user: myuser`]

I tried setting the `remote_user` to `myuser` in the palybook, but all results kept the same.

### My configuration / environment:

My `become` variables are configured like this:

```
ansible_connection: ssh
ansible_user: myuser
ansible_ssh_pass: 1234
ansible_become: yes
ansible_become_user: root
ansible_become_pass: 1234
```

The playbook looks like:

```
- hosts: myhost
  connection: local
  become: ansible_become
  become_user: ansible_become_user

  roles:
    - role: pulse-audio-config
```

Comment: You say pulseaudio starts as 'sudo', I presume you mean the root user. Try removing `ansible_become_user`: root` from your config; it may be overriding the task settings. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#directives

Comment: well, this is definitely a good hint, I got the command running now, but therefor others are failing - but this might be easier to figure out. I will report, if I found a solution that works for all requirements. But thanks so far! At least now I know it is possible ;)

Comment: @CalumHalpin thanks for pointing me in the right direction :) - I think setting `ansible_become_user` for the specific task did the job in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution:

After several different approaches I got it working with the following configuration:

The variables in the inventory:

```
ansible_connection: ssh
ansible_user: myuser
ansible_ssh_pass: 1234
ansible_become: yes
ansible_become_user: root
ansible_become_pass: 1234
```

in the playbook:

```
- hosts: myhost
  connection: local

  roles:
    - role: another-role
    - { role: pulse-audio-config,
      ansible_become_user: nas }
    - role: another-other-role
```

in the role:

```
- name: restart pulse audio
  shell: '$([[ $(pulseaudio -k) -eq 0 ]] || exit 0; sleep 5; [[ $(pulseaudio -D --exit-idle-time=-1) -eq 0 ]] || exit 0)'
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_flags: "su - {{ ansible_become_user }} -c"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your remote user has full sudo privileges:

```
- name: restart pulse audio
  shell: '$([[ $(pulseaudio -k) -eq 0 ]] || exit 0; sleep 5; [[ $(pulseaudio -D --exit-idle-time=-1) -eq 0 ]] || exit 0)'
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: myuser
```

Make sure `ansible_become_pass` is set to the remote user's password.

Alternatively set the become method to `su` and `ansible_become_pass` to `myuser`'s password.

Or if your playbook structure suits it you could set `remote_user` to `myuser`.

Make sure you don't have the become user set in the group or host vars since that will override the play/task setting: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#directives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately none of your suggestions had a different effect than my earlier attempts ..

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but I am facing the same problem. I think I found a pretty simple solution that works when the ansible user can sudo to myuser:

```
shell: 
  cmd: sudo su - myuser -c "ls -la"
```